# Uncheck others switch toggles when another switch toggle is marked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I'am trying to implement checking logic of switchToggles in React.
According to the condition of the task, it is necessary that only one switch can be checked. And if another switch is marked, the one that was marked before should be unchecked.

Switches are rendered in table rows (one per row) in a function that returns a fragment with buttons:

```
const renderButtons = (cell) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <SwitchToggle />
                <SettingsIcon className={joiner(st.toolsIcon, st.leftMargin)}/>
                <DeleteIcon className={st.toolsIcon}/>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
```

SwitchToggle is a component from Ant design:

```
export default function SwitchToggle({ checked, onChange }){
    return (
            <Switch
                className={st.switch}
                size={'small'}
                checkedChildren={'On'}
                unCheckedChildren={'Off'}
                onChange={onChange||null}
                checked={checked||undefined}
            />
    )
}
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like a radio button group. Some problems become trivial when you use the correct underlying semantic inputs.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I need styling like this switch. And yet, these switches are mapped line by line, and not in a group, so there is no connection between them. Essentially, they are not a group.

Comment: You can style elements, and the `name` attribute is what defines a group. Well, you should be able to store an "active" toggle id or index, something, and set the `checked` value based on that information, using the `onChange` to manage the state.

Comment: Can you share your table component where you are using `renderButtons`?